# Asp.net C# web service - oracle connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, oracle, connection

I have written one web service for employee leave request.

It has 3 Web Services…

Two are connecting to SQL data source and 1 connecting to oracle DB.

Please note that the Oracle [Web method] for NOT even showing when run it on Browser whereas the  other methods are invoked. Also note that I test this connecting setting and executed in asp. C# as a application method it works.

```
[WebMethod]       
public DataSet Leave_balance(string empNo)
{
    string oradb = "Data Source=hRPROD;UserId=HR;Password=hr;";
    //string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
    //    + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=esnaadhrsrv1)(PORT=1521))"
    //     + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=hr1)));"
    //     + "User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = oradb;
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    //cmd.CommandText = "Select * from emp_intranet_leave where reg_no='" + empNo + "'";
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from emp_intranet_leave";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("emp_no", OracleType.Int32).Value = 2415;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();
    return (ds);
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have mentioned what the problem is? Does it give any errors? If so, what are they and their stack traces? Does it silently fail?

Comment: Hmm you are returning a DataSet which reminds me of [Returning Datasets](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)

Comment: how do you even generate the wsdl for this?  How can wsdl.exe figure out what exactly you're returning?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dataset use class concept. trace whether data is retrieved from oracle database. if not getting data please check with your database connection. you can return data from webmethod either using list or string (xml) data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
 
Please note that i test this method in C# application it show sthe data in datagrid view.. I can pass the parameter also... when i put a webservice method it not giving any result or error.

Comment: please change the return type from dataset to class model. then check for the value.

Comment: is this working for u... pls make it as answer if it helps u.